# Force the_content() to show full post in RSS feed

Tags: rss, the-content

I'm making a custom RSS feed where I want the full article to display. The problem is that when I use the_content() to output the article, it will only show the excerpt if there is a 'more' tag in that article. How do I force the_content() to output the full article, or is there another function that will achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the $more variable to 0 seem to solve the problem for me. I put the following at the top of my function which output the RSS feed:

```
function outputRSS(){
    global $more;
    $more = 0;
    //Output my RSS below...
}
```

Comment: this is the way indeed

Answer (score 1):

The default setting on wordpress is work for me.

Go to wordpress dashboard-> setting -> reading
There are 2 option we can choose to show how article is displayed:

> For each article in a feed, show
>
> 1. Full text
> 2. Summary